# Bash Function -> Command not found

Tags: bash

Hi gusy I am trying to learn Bash and cannot seem to get this basic script to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

function system_info
{    
    echo "function system_info"
}

$(system_info)
```

I get a function: command not found issue.

Answer (score 25):

Bash is trying to evaluate the string that is outputted by the `system_info` function.  You'll want to try the following, which will just simply run the function:

```
system_info
```

or to store the outputted value to a variable:

```
value=$(system_info)
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what is wrong *and* what happens as a result.

Comment: my function is with two inputs parameter and echoes the result that seems not to work. it gives an error of `command not found`

Answer (score 5):

You need to invoke the function by saying:

```
system_info
```

`$(...)` is used for [*command substitution*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).

Answer (score 2):

Invoke the function inside the script with just the function name and execute the script from the *shell*

```
#!/bin/bash
function system_info {
echo "function system_info"
}
system_info
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

function system_info
{    
    echo "function system_info"
}

echo $(system_info)
```

Kind of redundant but it works without the command not found error.

Or This:

```
#!/bin/bash

function system_info
{    
  echo "function\n system_info"
}

printf "$(system_info)"
```

If you want to use newline character.

You can try this code in: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php